# how to use selenium code in unix

Tags: java, unix, selenium

I have a selenium code that uses chromedriver in windows. I have set the chromedriver using following:

ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();

When i execute it in Windows, It works fine.

But when i create a jar for my code and execute it in unix using (java -cp xyz.jar classname). I get following error:

```
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'sample.home.com', ip: '10.1.30.207', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_75'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:117)
        at com.snapdeal.hadoop.monitoring.hdfs_monitoring.HadoopM.main(HadoopM.java:68)
```

Can someone please confirm what changes  should be done in my script so that it can be run on unix machine?

Comment: Would you be open to using Firefox? I find I have fewer issues with it on Linux.

Comment: Are you setting chrome webdriver's binary path as Java Variables? something like `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/absolute/path/to/binary/chromedriver");` If you want to run the program via `jar file` then better to keep chrome binary path in properties file so that same file and jar can be referred on multiple systems.

Comment: To add to mk08's comment, exit code 127 indicates that a command was not found on the path.

Comment: let me try it with firefox.